# How do I make a button update a QT table?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

When the user clicks on a specific row and column and selects "Edit", there is a window that pops up declaring true or false. Everything works except the OK button which updates the table.

Illustrated below:

---

### |*Program Name,        Blocked*  |

### |Firefox,               True   |

### |Emacs,                False   |

Say the user clicks True on Firefox and changes permissions, how do I get the window to update the table to False on Firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with how QT works, e.g. signals & slots?

Comment: What are you using for the table?  A table widget?  A table view?  A block of widgets you did yourself?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [model/view](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html) and overloading the [setData](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) function, then the [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal must be emitted from the model to notify the view that the cell must be redrawn.